# Powershell Graph API: Cannot use AND within $search

Tags: powershell, graph

I don't seem to be able to use AND in $search.
Below just returns everything in the mailbox.

What did I do wrong?

```
$api = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/users/john.doe@domain.com.au/messages?$search="subject:XYZ" AND "from:jonathan.doe@domain.com.au"'
$messages = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($ConnectGraph.access_token)"} -ContentType application/json -Uri $api -Method Get
```

Comment: Can you provide the error message the API returns? Try to remove the `"` after `XYZ` and before `from`

Comment: You're a legend!  It works by removing the in-between "

Comment: @Swisstone may I ask you one more question?  Is true that $count does not work with $search in the same URL?

Comment: I don't know if you can use $count with $search, you'll have to try it.